# I cannot get ddft.js to work like the examples

Tags: jquery

I need to add drop down filters to the top of columns in a web page table and found  [ddtf.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Simple-jQuery-Dropdown-Table-Filter-Plugin-ddtf-js.html), which seemed to be perfect.

I added the file to my environment and project and made the changes to my code based on the example webpage... but nothing. I don't know if I'm missing something or if there's some odd reason, but it just doesn't seem to be working.

This is the code I'm trying to make work.

```
@model db.Models.ViewTestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SelectTest";
}
<div>
    <h2>Drop Down Test</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="testTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Output ID</th>
                    <th>Input ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Item ID</th>
                    <th>Note</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var rec in Model.TestList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink(@rec.OrderNumber, 
                                             "Index", 
                                             "DetailReport",
                                             new { ordernumber = @rec.OrderNumber },
                                             null)</td>
                        <td>@rec.OutputID</td>
                        <td>@rec.InputID</td>
                        <td>@rec.DocDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td>@rec.ItemID</td>
                        <td>@rec.Note</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="~/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ddtf.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery('testTable').ddTableFilter();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure where to find errors initially, I was looking for them to crop up in visual studio like when i'm debugging. However, I have encountered these:
-Bootstrapped manifest not allowed to use 'resource' directive
-ReferenceError: Globalize is not defined
-Loading failed for both of my scripts.
-Type Error jQuery(...).ddTableFilter is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out my problem. My issue came from the following lines of code:

```
<script src="~/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/ddtf.js"></script>
```

I needed to have a more fully qualified path to where these .js files resided in the project...

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ddtf.js"></script>
```

Once I changed that, it worked just fine.